# asp.net code generator keeps asking for package even though its already added

Tags: asp.net, .net

..........
general info:

OS: Linux mint Debbie

code-editor: vs code

tutorial i'm following :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code
...........
when i run:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator -h
```

i get this(and the options/args list) :

```
No code generators are available in this project. Please add the 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design' NuGet package to the project.Please add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.
```

the package is already added here us the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.7">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.7">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

when i try to create a a view I (predictably) get this:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator view -name myView
```

i get:

```
    Building project ...
Finding the generator 'view'...
No code generators found with the name 'view'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String codeGeneratorName)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design, uninstall this package and then try to re-install them.